# Titanium android textview based zindex bad behavior #appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium

My code works in iOS but not android.

I have several views, where a settings button makes a view visible with a higher zindex. That original view and the second view that I made visible both have textfields. When I make the 2nd view visible only a part of the view appears like below.

```
original view
```

[original view with text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3WNJ.png)

```
second added view with higher zindex
```

[original view second view w/ higher zindex partially visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zHnU.png)

The code for the original view

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor: '#F00',top: theTop});
T=Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor:"#000",top:theTop});
var textfield = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    color: 'black',
    height: '40dp',
    top: '5dp',
    left: '5dp',
    right: '50dp',
    style: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintTextColor:"black",
    hintText: 'Enter an address',
    backgroundColor: '#aaa',
    zindex:"1",
    paddingLeft: '5dp'
});
```

The code for the 2nd view made visible

```
E=Titanium.UI.createView({
    borderRadius:8,
    backgroundColor:"red",
    visible:"false",
    zindex:"9999",
    top:5,
    left:5,
    width:250,
    height:80
 });

P=Ti.UI.createTextField({
    height:"30dp",
    top:"8dp",
    left:"8dp",
    width:"200dp",
    zindex:"9999",
    style:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText:"ET API key",
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    paddingLeft:"5dp"
});
```

Again, this works fine in iOS but in android the 2nd view partially appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first view you don't set a any size, so it will default to fill its parent. On the second view you set a width of 250 and a height of 80. So isn't what you see in the screenshots exactly what you've set it to be? If you want the second one also to take full size, then remove the width/height.

Comment: The code works on iOS, where the textfield appears on top of the added view (as is the structure in the linked images), and both appear above the original view.

Comment: So yes, the first view fills the parent and has a two text fields (one shown in the image). Then, when I click a button, part of the second view appears, showing part of the textview in that view. What I wanted was how it appears in iOS, where the entire second view appears over the first.

Comment: Thanks Fokke, this was less a bad behavior and more that I was lucky that it worked in iOS. I looked again at the code after your comment and realized that I had used "dp" in some but not all dimensions. iOS interpreted them all as "dp",  but android was literal, where non-dp we direct pixels. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put a new view over another view by some button event, Try using the below code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
backgroundColor : '#EEE',
height : Ti.UI.FILL,
width : Ti.UI.FILL
});
win.add(view);
var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
top: 0,
backgroundColor : '#F00',
height : 200,
width : Ti.UI.FILL,
});
view.add(view1);
var textField1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
color : '#336699',
width : '90%',
height : '90%',
style : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
hintTextColor : "black",
hintText : 'Enter an address',
backgroundColor : '#aaa',
zindex : "1",
});
view1.add(textField1);

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
top: 0,
backgroundColor : '#0F0',
height : 200,
width : Ti.UI.FILL,
});
var textField2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
color : '#336699',
width : '90%',
height : '90%',
style : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
hintTextColor : "black",
hintText : 'Enter name',
backgroundColor : '#aaa',
zindex : "9999",
});
view2.add(textField2);

var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title: 'Hello',
top: 600,
width: 100,
height: 50
});
view.add(button1);
button1.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
view1.hide();
view.add(view2);
view2.show();
});

var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title: 'Hello1',
top: 700,
width: 100,
height: 50
});
view.add(button2);
button2.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
view2.hide();
view1.show();
});

win.open();
```

Comment: this already looks similar to my code, which already works in iOS, but not in Android. I did not want to hide the first view to show the second because there are other views in the window that I would occlude by invoking view2.hide() and view1.show(). While my code already works on iOS, I'll try modifying my code to use the method instead of changing the property. Thanks.